# How to call a method inside NightmareJs evaluate function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I am trying to organize my code to use Page Objects Pattern, so I basically create a module with a method in which I can encapsulate the page interaction.

I am trying to turn this:

```
it('my test step', (done) => {
        nightmare
            .wait()
            .evaluate(() => {
                return {
                    myname: document.querySelector('document-myname').innerHTML};
            })
            .then(({myname}) => {
                expect(myname).toEqual(`Jorge`);
            })
            .then(done, done.fail);
    });
```

Into this:

```
 var page = require('../util/ui/mypage');

it('my test step', (done) => {
        nightmare
            .wait()
            .evaluate(() => {
                return {
                    myname: page.getMyName()};
            })
            .then(({myname}) => {
                expect(myname).toEqual(`Jorge`);
            })
            .then(done, done.fail);
    });
```

mypage.js

```
function getMyName() {
      return myname: document.querySelector('document-myname').innerHTML;
}


module.exports = {
     getName: getName,
};
```

What happens is that I get

```
 - Failed: page is not defined
```

Comment: is the variable page in your global scope?

Comment: Yes I used 'use strict'; on top of file

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `page` variable as the second parameter in the evaluate method's callback as described in the [docs](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#evaluatefn-arg1-arg2). This is because evaluate method's callback has an isolated scope so node.js variables are not available directly:

```
var page = require('../util/ui/mypage');

it('my test step', (done) => {
        nightmare
            .wait()
            .evaluate((page) => {
                return {
                    myname: page.getMyName()};
            }, page)
            .then(({myname}) => {
                expect(myname).toEqual(`Jorge`);
            })
            .then(done, done.fail);
    });
```

Comment: It does work but now I am getting "  - Expected undefined to equal 'Jorge'.
" . Somehow it is not returning the expected value

Comment: 'page' returns as Undefined

Comment: I see your module has `getMyName` and you're exporting `getName`.

Comment: Also it's better to pass `getMyName` to evaluate method as a callback instead of calling it from inside.

Comment: For what it's worth: you can't pass methods across the IPC boundary, at least in the way you have it written.  Doing so requires stringifying the function and reconstructing it on the client, which can lead to strange side effects if you're not careful.